# How to turn a variable with multiple inputs into a list?

Tags: python-3.x

So in my code the user enters GTIN-8 codes depending on the amount of items they want. I am trying to split the entered input (to make it into a list) , but it is not working with me.

```
while True:
itemsneeded = input("How many items do you need?")
if itemsneeded.isnumeric() and int(itemsneeded) <= 5:
    break
GTIN=''
count=0
while count<int(itemsneeded):
        GTIN=(input('Please enter all GTIN-8 for all items'))
        if GTIN.isnumeric() and len(GTIN)==8:
            Num0=int(GTIN[0])*3
            Num1=int(GTIN[1])
            Num2=int(GTIN[2])*3
            Num3=int(GTIN[3])
            Num4=int(GTIN[4])*3
            Num5=int(GTIN[5])
            Num6=int(GTIN[6])*3
            Num7=int(GTIN[7])
            total2=(Num0+Num1+Num2+Num3+Num4+Num5+Num6+Num7)
            if total2 % 10 == 0:
                print(GTIN)
                if GTIN in open('read_it.txt').read():
                    print('entered GTIN is valid')
                else:
                    print('The code entered is invalid')
                    print('Please renter this code')

            count+=1
        else:
            print("The entered GTIN-8 codes are incorrect")
            print(GTIN)
            list = GTIN.split()
            print(list)
```

(last 2 lines)

Comment: Are you getting any errors/exceptions? If you're not, how doesn't the `split` method work? What output do you get? May I ask why you want to split the incorrect input in the first place?

Comment: Oh , I think you just fixed my problem....

Comment: Well, I'm glad to help. How'd you fix it?